# Symfony2 Doctrine Mapped superclass annotations not found for different bundle

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine, symfony

Symfony 2.8 + doctrine

I have two Bundles: `CoreBundle` and `BonusBundle`

`CoreBundle` have folder Model containing *abstract* class `ClassA`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//[...]

abstract class ClassA
{

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

and in another directory Entity - `ClassB`:

```
//[...]
/**
 * ClassB
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ClassB extends ClassA
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

}
```

Currently this working well, ClassB inherit `name` property and this way we have mapped Entity `ClassB` with `id` and `name`.

I added in Model directory of `BonusBundle` (second one) other abstract class `ClassC`. Its the same as ClassA but in other bundle.

And now last key thing to my example - I added `ClassD` in `CoreBundle` (Entity directory) extending ClassC from `BonusBundle` (the same way as above).

### My problem

In result I recived ClassB with properties `id`, `name` and ClassD only with `id` property.

I cannot understand why this happen. Its looks like doctrine ignore annotations if superclass lives in other Bundle. I checked some docs and other questions but I can't find understand what happening.
[I see in config docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) that `auto_mapping` option checking Entity directory:

> Doctrine's auto_mapping feature loads annotation configuration from
>   the Entity/ directory of each bundle and looks for other formats (e.g.
>   YAML, XML) in the Resources/config/doctrine directory.

and

> If it wasn't possible to determine a configuration format for a
>   bundle, the DoctrineBundle will check if there is an Entity folder in
>   the bundle's root directory. If the folder exist, Doctrine will fall
>   back to using an annotation driver.

in my project this folder exist in both `Bundles`. And If symfony check only Entity folder then why first example (Model) working well?
**How this mechanism works?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In completion of @Griva answer about the `MappedSuperClass`, here is an simple example of how to tell Doctrine to look for mapped classes in other folders than Entity:

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle;

    use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

    class AppBundle extends Bundle
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
        {
            parent::build($container);

            // With Yaml configuration format
            $container->addCompilerPass(DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createYamlMappingDriver(array(
                realpath(__DIR__ . '/Resources/config/doctrine-mapping') => 'AppBundle\Model'
            )));

            // With annotation configuration format
            $container->addCompilerPass(DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createAnnotationMappingDriver(array(
                'AppBundle\Model'
            )));
        }
    }
```

There are Doctrine MappingsPass available for MongoDB and CouchDB too.

Comment: Oh yeah - nice. You did the homework so points should be yours but there is the last part. What is the difference that if you extending class in the same bundle it works without even `MappedSuperClass` but from other bundle you need this annotation or compilerpass. I missed something?

Comment: I've never encounter this case, so I don't have an answer for this. Did your parent class was in the Entity folder of the same bundle? I guess the anotations could be read from the entity even if the annotations `@ORM\Entity` or `@ORM\MappedSuperClass` are not present, even if it seems it shouln't be a normal behaviour.

Comment: it's excatly as i wrote in question. Bundle1/Model/ClassA as parent for Bundle1/Entity/ClassB working well but Bundle1/Model/ClassA as parent for Bundle2/Entity/ClassC not working :( Class is extended and have properties but Annotation from parent not working so database is not updated and data mapped...

Comment: I have no idea either... If mapping format of ClassA and ClassC was not the same (like ClassA in yaml and ClassC in annotation) it could make sense, but here I'm totally helpless... :(

Comment: Really nice job! I'm glad you could find an answer for this, now the mistery is finally solved! That's the kind of knowledge that can be useful for future cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I tested some possibilities and I found solution to fix it but still no idea why this happen.

If I add annotation to superclass `@ORM\MappedSuperclass()` then mappings are loaded correctly but only if class is located in `Entity` directory.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ClassA
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
 */
abstract class ClassA
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

This way my annotations are visible in other `Bundles` and my `ClassA` is not `Entity` itself.

Still I dont understand why it works if class exist in the same Bundle but in other directory. In addition inside FoSUserBundle exist similar example using `MappedSuperclass()` - `FOSUserBundle/Model/User.php` but its located in Model directory and still working.

---

**//EDIT**

*Completion to @Boulzy answer*

Probably i found answer for second part - why it can see mapping from other directory but the same bundle. After analysing other working example I found that mapped property with strict access `private` is not visible for child class but `protected` property is visible, mapped and don't need `@ORM\MappedSuperclass()` annotation as long as it used in the same `Bundle`.

It seems that `@ORM\MappedSuperclass()` give us possibility to map even `private` properties and this way they are visible and mapped for other classes in any other bundle (as long as it lives in Entity or other mapped directory).

Comment: I ran on the same issue and came to the same conclusion as you... I'm still triggered by the FOSUserBundle example. Have you learnt anything new about how we can use a MappedSuperClass that is not in the Entity folder? Thank you!

Comment: So, I did some digging into FOSUserBundle code, it turns out that this is what we're looking for: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserBundle.php I'll post an answer to complete yours with a simple example of how to achieve that.